# Accessing child table fields in an entity using JSF EL within a datatable

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, el

Being somewhat new to JSF and JPA I'm relying heavily on Netbeans auto-generated code to create entities, facades and managed beans. I have a User table that contains several nested child tables relating to County, Country, etc with the usual constraints applied.

All was going well until I started creating a JSF page to display all Users within the database using a DataTable construct. I'm trying to replace the numerical FK values with the text data that is refers to in the child table. The JSF framework defaults to displaying this data as it "knows" the countryID field is a foreign key but I know that countryID actually contains a Country object and therefore the data I want. I can't seem to find the correct EL syntax to extract and display the CountryNAME field from the Country object referred to by CountryID. I'm sure the information is out there but I don't think I'm asking the right question...

User entity (simplified excerpt):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@XmlRootElement
public class Users implements Serializable {
....=
    @JoinColumn(name = "Country_ID", referencedColumnName = "Country_ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Country countryID;
...
```

Country entity (simplified):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Country")
@XmlRootElement
...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Country_ID")
    private Integer countryID;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "Country_NAME")
    private String countryNAME;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "countryID")
    private Collection<User> userCollection;
...
```

JSF managed bean (excerpt):

```
@Named("userController")
@SessionScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable {

    private User current;
    private DataModel items = null;
    @EJB
    private jpa.session.UserFacade ejbFacade;
    private PaginationHelper pagination;
    private int selectedItemIndex;
...
    public PaginationHelper getPagination() {
        if (pagination == null) {
            pagination = new PaginationHelper(10) {
                @Override
                public int getItemsCount() {
                    return getFacade().count();
                }

                @Override
                public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                    return new ListDataModel(getFacade().findRange(new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}));
                }
            };
        }
        return pagination;
    }
....
```

JSF page:

```
                    <h:dataTable value="#{userController.items}" var="item" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px">
 ...
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUserTitle_countryID}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.countryID.countryID}"/>
                        </h:column>
...
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Override `toString`() method in Country entity. By default it will return the hashcode of Object. If you want country name than design your `toString()` method as follows.

```
@Override.
public String toString(){
   return countryNAME;
}
```

**OR,**

Call `countryName` in EL expression.

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.countryID.countryNAME}" />
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! I'd already overridden toString() but hadn't changed my field name. That's what you get for using auto-generated code without understanding what it actually does (I've spent two days wondering why item.countryID gave me a Country object rather than an Integer FK reference to the country table!)

Comment: Noted should be that overriding the `toString()` for this purpose is a very bad practice and that the user in question blatantly copypasted my (currently deleted) answer within grace period into his "OR" section without attribution. My ignore list is now one user richer.

Comment: @BalusC - I'd actually overridden toString() to give a user-centric representation of the object in another view (user edit page - the selectOne listboxes don't make much sense otherwise). Should I be implementing this a different way? Out of curiosity, why is it bad practice? (sorry - total newbie question I'm sure) I was under the impression that overriding this method didn't generally have repercussions (unlike hashCode() or equals() for example)